# Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, babeljs

I have `Node + Express + Babel + ES6` project with the following files:

`/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "babel-node src/index.mjs",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir build",
    "start": "node build/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "babel-plugin-module-extension": "^0.1.3"
  }
}
```

`/.babelrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: ['@babel/transform-runtime', ['module-extension', { mjs: 'js' }]],
  sourceMaps: false,
  retainLines: false,
  minified: true,
};
```

`/src/index.mjs`

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { sum } from './utils.mjs';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const result = sum(3, 2);
  res.send(`current dir: ${__dirname} | sum(3, 2) = ${result}`);
})

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

`src/utils.mjs`

```
export const sum = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;
```

I can properly test the website with the command:

```
$ npm run dev
```

Then going to: http://localhost:8080

I can properly build the website with the command:

```
$ npm run build
```

Which will generate a new directory: `/build`.

**My problem is:** When I try to run the built website with command:

```
$ npm start
```

I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module`. Below you have the full error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> test-backend@1.0.0 start
> node build/index.js

D:\myproject\build\index.js:1
"use strict";var _interopRequireDefault=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");var _express=_interopRequireDefault(require("express"));var _path=_interopRequireDefault(require("path"));var _url=require("url");var _utils=require("./utils.js");var _filename=(0,_url.fileURLToPath)(import.meta.url);var _dirname=_path["default"].dirname(_filename);var app=(0,_express["default"])();app.get("/",function(req,res){var result=(0,_utils.sum)(3,2);res.send("current dir: ".concat(_dirname," | sum(3, 2) = ").concat(result))});var port=8080;app.listen(port,function(){console.log("Example app listening on port ".concat(port))});
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

The issue indicates it is caused because the following lines on: `/src/index.mjs`:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
```

Here is the transpiled `/build/index.js`

```
"use strict";
var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
var _express = _interopRequireDefault(require("express"));
var _path = _interopRequireDefault(require("path"));
var _url = require("url");
var _utils = require("./utils.js");
var _filename = (0, _url.fileURLToPath)(import.meta.url);
var _dirname = _path["default"].dirname(_filename);
var app = (0, _express["default"])();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  var result = (0, _utils.sum)(3, 2);
  res.send("current dir: ".concat(_dirname, " | sum(3, 2) = ").concat(result));
});
var port = 8080;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Example app listening on port ".concat(port));
});
```

where you can see the code uses: `import.meta.url` which is the conflicting line.

**My requirements are:**

- Need to get the current working directoy because I have resources in there that I need for the app to run.
- Need the source code to be: `ES6` so I can use classes, imports, exports, etc.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Do you need the build to be CommonJS or ESM?**

For an **ESM build** on a supported Node version you can:

- Update `package.json`

  ```json
  "type": "module"
  ```
- Update `./babelrc.js`:

  ```js
    export default {
       presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
       // The rest is the same ...
    }
  ```

About the [`modules`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules) setting

> Setting this to false will preserve ES modules.

Now run

```
npm run build
npm start
```

Alternatively, you can use babel's [`--out-file-extension`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#set-file-extensions) option and use `.mjs` in your build script. You would still need to update `@babel/preset-env` to preserve the ES module system. I think it is cleaner and clearer to use `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` whenever you want to use ES modules.

For a **CommonJS build** you would need to:

- Rename your files from `.mjs` to `.js` so the heuristic for [determining the module system](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) isn't toggling between ESM and CommonJS for dev/build runs.
- Remove usage of `import.meta` and use the [`__dirname` global](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname) available to CommonJS modules.

Comment: Hello! Im confused on "Remove usage of import.meta and use the __dirname global" for CommonJS - If I have something like new URL('some-path', import.meta.url) -- then what is the equivalent with __dirname that youre suggesting @morganney

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the transpiled code didnt transpile `import.meta.url`

Since babel is the transpiler, I think we can circle in on that being the focus

Maybe try this babel plugin to transform `import.meta` when transpiling: https://github.com/javiertury/babel-plugin-transform-import-meta/

Comment: Seems like the documentation of the package is not clear,