# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module - Webpack + React + babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I try build react app with webpack and babel. But after succses bulding open app i get next exseption:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module (at main.a60bd865a2badb5e3d45.js:37369:29)"

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "new_live",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "DIVAYTH",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --env port=3000",
    "build:dev": "webpack --env mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --env mode=production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

// webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const webpack = require("webpack")

const paths = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.jsx"),
    build: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    html: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
};

const DEV = "development";

module.exports = function (env) {
    const MODE = env.mode || DEV;
    const PORT = env.port || 3000;

    const isDev = MODE === DEV;

    return {
        mode: MODE,
        entry: paths.entry,
        experiments: {
            outputModule: true,
        },
        output: {
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
            path: paths.build,
            clean: true,
            module: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: paths.html}),
            new webpack.ProgressPlugin()
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
                        }
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        },
        devtool: isDev && 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: isDev && {
            port: PORT,
            open: true
        }
    };
};
```

libs :'webpack-external-import/babel-plugin' not help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250705/cannot-use-import-meta-outside-a-module)